# Update and Insert into SQL Server database using XML via C# WPF App

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I to use the following XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<ty>
-<ry>
<EMPID>1</EMPID>
<EMPName>Thabo</EMPName>
<EMPRole>Developer </EMPRole>
<EMPAddress>227 Complex B WoodMans Road Claremont</EMPAddress>
<EMPEmail>Thabecoo@hotmail.com</EMPEmail>
<EMPNumber>083 577 8910</EMPNumber>
</ry>

-<ry>
<EMPID>2</EMPID>
<EMPName>Aldrin</EMPName>
<EMPRole>Analyst </EMPRole>
<EMPAddress>65 Mfecane Avenue</EMPAddress>
<EMPEmail>AGFFHH@tommail.com</EMPEmail>
<EMPNumber>0872343352</EMPNumber>
</ry>

-<ry>
<EMPID>4</EMPID>
<EMPName>Amoleng</EMPName>
<EMPRole>Engineer </EMPRole>
<EMPAddress>43 Pixely KaSeme Street</EMPAddress>
<EMPEmail>AmoT@axxess.co.za</EMPEmail>
<EMPNumber>0765546832</EMPNumber>
</ry>

-<ry>
<EMPID>5</EMPID>
<EMPName>Nathi</EMPName>
<EMPRole>Executive </EMPRole>
<EMPAddress>54 Steve Biko Road</EMPAddress>
<EMPEmail>nat544787@gmail.com</EMPEmail>
<EMPNumber>0834567656</EMPNumber>
</ry>
</ty>
```

I want to use this XML called `Oldtable.xml` to update a SQL database table called `tblemp`. I'm using a WPF App and I want it to be done using C#. The database has the exact same columns such as `<EMPID>` and `<EMPName>`. I want it to take the XML data and update existing entries accordingly(if there is a new entry it must add it). Alternatively if it is simpler to turn `tblemp` into a XML file and update the new XML file and have the app read that new XML I am open to doing it that way.Thanks in advance.
This is what I've tried so far

```
void main()
{
    string FILENAME = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Connection.xml");

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

    string conn = xdoc.Descendants("connectionStrings").FirstOrDefault().Value;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblEMP] SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tblEMP1] WHERE [EMPID]=[EMPID] ";

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(@"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Oldtable.xml");

        var attributeName = "EMPID";
        var element = xdoc.Descendants("ry").FirstOrDefault(el => el.Attribute(attributeName) != null);
    }
}
```

This is how I have it so far but I'm not sure how to structure the SQL statement as I am new to it.

Please help me structure the C# code better.

To explain it more, `Oldtable.xml` is the xml with the data above, `Connection.xml` is an xml I'm using to connect to the SQL Server database in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: Is your question how to extract the data or how to update a database? Big difference.

Comment: It is better to pass the entire XML as a parameter to a stored procedure (SP). That SP will shred XML and use MERGE to INSERT/UPDATE the existing DB table.

Comment: @mm8 It is how to update the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication193
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string Path = "Enter your path here";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string FILENAME = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Connection.xml");
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Add your connection string here"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblEMP] (EMPID, EMPName, EMPRole, EMPAddress, EMPMail, EMPNumber) VALUES (@EMPID, @EMPName, @EMPRole, @EMPAddress, @EMPMail, @EMPNumber)";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMPID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMPName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMPRole", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMPAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMPMail", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMPNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                   
                    foreach (XElement ry in xdoc.Descendants("ry"))
                    {
                        string empId = (string)ry.Element("EMPID");
                        string empName = (string)ry.Element("EMPName");
                        string empRole = (string)ry.Element("EMPRole");
                        string empAddress = (string)ry.Element("EMPAddress");
                        string empEmail = (string)ry.Element("Email");
                        string empNumber = (string)ry.Element("EMPNumber");

                        cmd.Parameters["@EMPID"].Value = empId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@EMPName"].Value = empName;
                        cmd.Parameters["@EMPRole"].Value = empRole;
                        cmd.Parameters["@EMPAddress"].Value = empAddress;
                        cmd.Parameters["@EMPMail"].Value = empEmail;
                        cmd.Parameters["@EMPNumber"].Value = empNumber;
 
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
            }
 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass the whole XML to the server and shred it in SQL using the `.nodes` function.

This obviates the need for looping on the C# side, and is likely to perform much better.

> Please correct the data types for the columns, as I do not have access to your schema

```cs
void main()
{
    string FILENAME = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Connection.xml");

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    string connStr = xdoc.Descendants("connectionStrings").FirstOrDefault().Value;

    const string query = @"
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblEMP]
    (EMPID, EMPName, EMPRole, EMPAddress, EMPMail, EMPNumber)
SELECT
    x.ry.value('EMPID', 'int'),
    x.ry.value('EMPName', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    x.ry.value('EMPRole', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    x.ry.value('EMPAddress', 'nvarchar(1000)'),
    x.ry.value('EMPMail', 'nvarchar(200)'),
    x.ry.value('EMPNumber', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/ty/ry') x(ry);
";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml).Value =
            new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Oldtable.xml")));
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```